# Disabling a Navigation Bar Button Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

When setting the right navigation bar button to disabled, it does not change its color to signal its disabled state to the user.

It remains "highlighted", non-greyed-out.

I have set up the button in Storyboard as follows:

[image]

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

What do I need to do to change the button`s state visually too?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it a custom button? Setting enabled to FALSE should dim a regular UIBarButtonItem

Comment: What happens if you add the Done button programatically instead?

Comment: I can`t because I hard coded a segue based on the button in Storyboard.

Answer (score 5):

Credit to **Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspo** for this answer.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

This automatically seems to grey out the buttons and also disables them.

**NOTE:** The assumption in the question that *self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;* 
works seems to be wrong, after trialling it in my code I found it had no effect.

Again thanks to Vijay noting that it might be better to use:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

As Apple doesn't like disabling the back button.

Personally I am going to disable the top right button and hide the back button to stop the user from pressing them, then enable them again when I choose.

A link to the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362050/how-to-disable-a-navigation-bar-button-item-in-ios)

This answer is posted for completeness and so future users don't need to continue searching past this page.

Answer (score 5):

None of the relevant answers were able to produce the result I was looking for - but I was able to solve this by setting the text attributes on my navigation buttons:

```
[navButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:enabledColor} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:disabledColor} forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Then, all I need to do is the following and the user interactability and color changes automatically:

```
navButton.enabled = YES; // or NO
```

Comment: I love that I just ran into this issue a month after I posted a solution, and my own solution answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
[[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:0] setEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Update it to:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually change the tint colour like this:

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

This is untested code, but it should work. Also, don't forget to change it back when it's enabled again.

Comment: Should be `[UIColor grayColor]`