# how to disable a navigation bar button item in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have created a navigation controller. In the second view (which is pushed), I have some webservice call and placing a overlay view and setting

`self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO ;`

Once web service call is complete, then I am reverting to

`self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES ;`

When I do this, every other buttons except the buttons on the navigation bar are disabled. How to disable those two navigation bar button items ? (a button similar to back button, which pops to first view controller and another button which gives info about help).

I have tried using `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.enabled = NO`. But still I am able to tap on the button and can navigate to first screen. How can I disable these two buttons ?

Answer (score 59):

Try this

Recommended

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Or Simply Disable by

on Edge case

```
self.view.window.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

**Update:**
Recently Apple doesn't allow the back button to enable / disable. Instead of that we can hide it.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: Both didn't work. I am still able to tap the button and navigate to the first view controller.

Comment: @Sravan Are you building the buttons in storyboard or dynamically? Building dynamically may have impact I suppose. Try placing this logic after you added the buttons to the navigationbar

Answer (score 16):

You can do the following if you are running on `Swift`

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled = true
```

This snippet will disable the button.

Comment: This works fine!

Answer (score 9):

Just disable your `UINavigationController` view and navigation bar interaction:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

And enable it when you need it back:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: This didnt worked. I am still able to tap the button and navigate to frist view controller.

Comment: @Sravan I just edited my answer, does it work better?

Comment: disabling interaction is fine and you can disable a button at a time, navigation bar buttons or the entire window. However, be sure you can always enable them. You might want to consider wrapping the 'disable' logic in a timer. For example, imagine you started a download but it did not finish correctly, is your app going to hang? Do you want to trigger a retry? Enable all?

Comment: self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO; freezes whole screen? I don't think it will work?

Answer (score 7):

Latest Swift: To hide the back button, you MUST use:

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

Note: This can trigger a bug in the navigation bar that can cause an artifact to appear in place of a hidden back button when transitioning to a view that doesn't have a back button (or has a leftButton in its place).  The artifact that appears is either ellipses "..." or the title of the previous viewController on the stack.  I believe this bug to be related to the bug  documented in apple's own sample code project "CustomizingUINavigationBar", CustomBackButtonViewController.m

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Updated for Swift 3:

**If you want to disable a navigation bar button item OR you want to disable hole UINavigationBar i.e. all item present on navigation bar, use below lines of code;**

```
// if you want disable
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

// if you want enable again
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Enjoy...!

Answer (score 3):

This code should work on Swift 4.2

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
```

The above code will disable the button. To enable it switch the boolean to true

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

This will stop user to interaction with app and after service call, write this code again:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

Sure this will help.

Comment: 'beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()' was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Answer (score 2):

For version iOS 10.3, swift 3:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false.
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to truly disable a UIBarButtonItem would be as followed:

```
barButtonVar.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by just adding a property to my viewcontroller:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * RightButton;
```

I then connected it to the button on the storyboard.
You can then at will set its properties like:

```
self.RightButton.enabled=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

**One line solution**

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 & iOS 13 :**

To remove all left buttons or just a specified one just remove from `leftBarButtonItems` Array.

```
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = []
```

Answer (score -1):

Navigation bar button items must be toggled by referring to them via the navigationItem property.

For example:

```
func setupNav() {
    let saveButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(onSavePressed))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton
    saveButton.isEnabled = false
  }

func validateSave() {
     saveButton.isEnabled = isConditionMet // WON'T work
      navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.isEnabled = isConditionMet // WORKS!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false;
```

Comment: `.isEnabled` has already been mentioned in several other answers. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

```
var menuBtn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
menuBtn.Frame = new CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 20, height: 20);
menuBtn.SetImage(new UIImage("filter"), UIControlState.Normal);

menuBtn.Alpha = 0.05f;   //to set the Alpha

menuBtn.Enabled = false;
```

tested on Mvvmcross Xamarin.iOS only