# How to disable back button in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Is there any official way how to set `UIBarButtonItem.enabled` property? I tried to set a backButtonItem in previous controller. But `enabled` property is ignored.

More in this simple [example project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vvnyalf69l4a621/BackButton.zip?dl=0).

I don't want to some solution like "make your own leftBarButtonItem and set its alpha ..."

Edit: I don't want to hide it, only disable it with dimmed colour and disabled user interaction. It's exactly the same behaviour as for disabled `leftBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 105):

As of today it is not possible to disable the back button using the `enabled` property. The `backBarButtonItem` property will be `nil` unless you create a custom item and even then it will ignore the `enabled` property. There are a couple (non-satisfactory) ways around this.

## Hide the button

This is what Apple wants you to do given that they ignore the `enabled` property. It is as simple as

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

and should be the preferred approach unless you have good reasons.

## Disable and Tint the Navigation Bar

You can disable user interaction on the whole navigation bar and tint it to make the back button appear disabled.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
```

This does, unfortunately, affect other elements in the navigation bar as well so it might not be an option if, for instance, you have another bar button item on the right side.

## Use a Custom Left Bar Button Item

The `leftBarButtonItem` does not ignore the `enabled` property so you could create a custom item and trigger the pop manually when it is activated.

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ThisClass.backButtonTapped))
...
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false

func backButtonTapped() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This will, however, not have the back bar button style with the leading triangular indicator.

Comment: I don't want to lose default back gesture and the leading triangular indicator. It looks like it's not possible to achieve this. Thank you for long answer.

Comment: Nav bar userInteractionEnabled  = NO doesn't seem to work for me on iOS 10? Anybody else have this problem?

Comment: I want to add a button just right to back button. When i use leftBarButtonItem then back button automatic hides. Any solution to show both button at a time with back button default functionality of navigation controller.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying I could disable a custom bar Button? I was able to do that, yet by setting it disabled, I'm unable to make it have a lighter looking color. Is there a built in functionality for that?

Answer (score 13):

Add below code in your ViewController2.swift Class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
    }
```

It will hide your back button.

Comment: I have try all possible option but its not possible to disable the back button look the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362050/how-to-disable-a-navigation-bar-button-item-in-ios, Either you have to create custom back button.

Comment: It hides and disables. Question was how to disable button.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to hide it, `UInavigationItem` has a `hidesBackButton` property.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but this may help someone else.
As mentioned by hennes, you can no longer disable the back button. Instead, you will need to disable the entire navigationBar.

The approach I took, was disabling the navigationBar, and then applying an 0.5 alpha to the subviews of the navigation bar.

In your ViewController class:

```swift
    func changeBarButtons(alpha: CGFloat) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.forEach { firstViews in
            firstViews.subviews.forEach { view in
                if ["_UIButtonBarButton", "_UIButtonBarStackView"].contains(type(of: view).description()) {
                    view.alpha = alpha
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func set(loading: Bool) {
        let alpha: CGFloat = loading ? 0.5 : 1
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = !loading

        changeBarButtons(alpha: alpha)
    }
```

Keep in mind, that Apple could change the names of the class any time. That being said, it's highly unlikely they do so. If you don't mind the title of the View Controller fading out, you can apply the alpha to all the subviews, without checking the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to disable your custom back button (won't work), just set a new one which is disabled. You can reach the previous navigation item through the `UINavigationBar.backItem` property.

```
// set disabled back button
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
backButton.isEnabled = false
navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem = backButton

// disable pop gesture
navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
```